# Filter array by value only if value is defined

Tags: arrays, typescript, filtering

How can I peform this filter but only check each condition if the value is not `undefined`?
For example, if `taxId` is undefined I want to ignore it instead of filtering by it.

```
this.subAgencies = demoSubAgencies.filter(function(subAgency) {
  return subAgency.subAgencyName == agencyName
    && subAgency.taxId == taxId
    && subAgency.accountNumber == accountNumber;
});
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use "or" statements between the "and" groups like the below :

```
this.subAgencies = demoSubAgencies.filter(function(subAgency) {
  return (subAgency.subAgencyName == agencyName || !agencyName ) 
    && (subAgency.taxId == taxId || !taxId)
    && (subAgency.accountNumber == accountNumber || !accountNumber ) ;
});
```

Comment: Works great, thank you